# Adding white-space to the output of a variable - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've justed started learning to code in Ruby and have hit a snag in my first script. The idea is to translate the English alphabet into morse code.

I have set up a hash for my letters and their corresponding values:

```
morse_code = {
'a' => '.-',
'b' => '-...',
etc etc
```

I use the following to iterate through the hash and pull the corresponding values based on input then output it:

```
print "What would you like to translate: "
code = gets.strip.downcase
morse_code.each do |morse, alpha|
   code.gsub!( morse, alpha )
end

puts code
```

The problem is that my output does not contain spacing so looks like this:

```
......-...-..----
```

instead of what I want:

```
.... . .-.. .-.. --- -
```

All I've found thus far are relating to adding a whitespace when calling variables inside a string. Below is an example:

[Putting space between the output of defined variables in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938900/putting-space-between-the-output-of-defined-variables-in-ruby)

Any help on how I can achieve this with my current code or rewrite it accordingly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to take the input and map its characters to corresponding values from the `morse_code` hash, and then join it with spaces:

```
code = 'abb'
code.each_char.map { |letter| morse_code[letter] }.join(' ')
#=> ".- -... -..."
```

Reference:

- [String#`each_char`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-each_char)
- [Enumerable#`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)
- [Array#`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

## EDIT:

To make your initial code to work the only thing you lacked is a space, which is easy to add using interpolation:

```
code = 'abab'
morse_code.each do |morse, alpha|
  code.gsub!(morse, "#{alpha} ") # <=============
end

code
#=> ".- -... .- -... "
code.rstrip
#=> ".- -... .- -..."
```

If you did not know about interpolation - here is how it works:

foo = 'bar'
"#{foo}"            #=> "bar"
"hello I am #{foo}" #=> "hello I am bar"

So going back to your case, all the following does

```
"#{alpha} "
```

is adding a space after, which you needed. Problem with it, that the resulting string will have an extra space at the end, which we solved with

```
code.rstrip
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? This doesn't look like his code __at all__ :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev actually just did :)

Comment: Yeah, but not really :) This concept of `map` is hard for newbies to grasp, I found. So your explanation may very well not mean anything to DaftVader. If I were to answer, I'd take his code and transform it step-by-step, with explanations and outputs, etc.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev well... From what I remember `map` for a long time was almost the only thing I understood from programming in Ruby, so quite different experiences there :)

Comment: @mr_sudaca yep, `each_char` is a better option that splitting the string, edited

Comment: @Stefan I meant it to be `string << morse_code[char] << ' '` but this will still add extra space at the end.. Probably will remove this option.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thanks for the help. I am however not entirely sure how to implement this into my code block, have tried different variations and understand in theory what you are saying but haven't had any luck. Could you possibly further elaborate?

Comment: @DaftVader this line is a complete solution, which constitutes the block you have had, so you prompt user for input (`print "What would you like to translate: "`), then modify it (`code = gets.strip.downcase`) and then you run the piece I've shown in the answer.

Comment: @DaftVader I'll edit the answer to make your initial code working, gimme a sec

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it works! So simple yet so effective. Thanks a lot!